# Detect Nullable change

Tags: c#, nullable-reference-types

I am trying to figure out, how I can tell the compiler that my `CancellationToken` `_loadingCts` is not null when I call the function `ClearCancellationTokenSource`

```
private CancellationTokenSource? _loadingCts = null;
     
private async Task LoadDataAsync()
{
    ClearCancellationTokenSource(_loadingCts, true);
    await foreach (var item in service.GetDataAsync(_loadingCts.Token))
    {

    }
}

private void ClearCancellationTokenSource(CancellationTokenSource? cts, bool createNewTokenSource = false)
{
    cts?.Cancel();
    cts?.Dispose();

    if(createNewTokenSource)
    {
        cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    }
}
```

As you can see in my code eaxample above `_loadingCts` is not null when I call the function before with true because it get's initialized within this method.

When I am trying to access `_loadingCts.Token` after I called this method with true I am getting a compiler warning CS8602.

Is there any way to fix this? I don't want to do another another nulöl check just to get rid off the warning. The `!` is not an option either because the warnings will be displayed again when I am trying to access anything from my `CancellationTokenSource` again.

Comment: Can you post a complete error and some details about your compiler? Ideally we want to see [mcve].

Comment: You are not passing it as ref  so your line `cts = new CancellationTokenSource();` will not change the `_loadingCts`status

Comment: Either way, the compiler has no way of being sure that `_loadingCts` isn't going to be null, so it's a valid warning. If you don't want it to be bull, then don't make it nullable.

Comment: Why do you need a parameter anyway when you are working on a field? Simply access `_loadingCts` directly in the method. Also `Clear...` is not a good name for a method recreating an object.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes this code is run within a ASP.NET Core Blazor server context where it can be called by many different async methods. Each method has it's own CancellationTokenSource. This method only exists to prevent writing the same code in many methods over and over again. You can pass in a different CTS from any other method and I want to get rid off the nullable warning for the passed in CTS if the second parameter is set to true. I changed the the param to ref already. Why do I need to pass it by ref btw.? I thought classes are always passed by reference.

Comment: 1. Each object should be responsible for its own `CancellationTokenSource`. It makes no sense to pass the method the one of another object. 2. You can pass a reference by value or by reference. See: [Passing Reference-Type Parameters (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/passing-reference-type-parameters). It says: *When you pass a reference-type parameter by value, it is possible to change the data belonging to the referenced object [...]. However, you cannot change the value of the reference itself;*

Answer (score 0):

```cs
using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis;

// ...

private void DisposeCancellationTokenSource(CancellationTokenSource? cts)
{
    cts?.Cancel();
    cts?.Dispose();
}

private void RecreateCancellationTokenSource([NotNull] ref CancellationTokenSource? cts)
{
    ClearCancellationTokenSource(cts);
    cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
}
```

The `[NotNull]` attribute tells the compiler that the argument to parameter `cts` will contain a not-null value after the call. It's not possible to make the NotNull conditional on the value of another bool parameter, so the easiest thing is to split your method into two methods instead of having one method with a bool parameter.

The `ref` makes it so when you assign a new object to the variable passed to the method, that new object is actually visible to the caller. Otherwise, it's only possible to make caller-visible changes by changing state on the same object. Because only `Recreate` assigns a new object, it's the only one that needs the `ref`--`Clear` doesn't need it.